# Spring Boot reduce download time of large CSV file

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, spring-mvc, response-time

I have an API for downloading a CSV file which can be huge in size(up to 15MB). Although the response time is pretty high, it is giving a response in Chrome. However, in Safari, it shows 504 Gateway timeout after 60 secs. Here is the code for that:

```
public File dataToCSV(List<String[]> dataLines) throws IOException {

    File csvOutputFile = new File("supply_tracker_" + LocalDateTime.now() + ".csv");
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(csvOutputFile)) {
        dataLines.stream()
                .map(data -> String.join(",", data))
                .forEach(pw::println);
    }
    return csvOutputFile;
}

public ResponseEntity<Object> getFile(File csv) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (csv != null) {
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(csv));
        long length = csv.length();
        boolean delete = csv.delete();
        if (delete) {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", csv.getName()));
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .headers(headers)
                    .contentLength(length)
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv"))
                    .body(resource);
        }
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body(null);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
}
```

What are the ways to reduce the response time? Also, is there a temporary solution to make this work on Safari? The front-end is in React and the API works on axios calls.

Comment: You could look at request timeout configuration for spring boot - but it seems to me like the safari client is timing out. Compressing the file before returning to the client would make the package smaller and should reduce the download time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a `ResponseBodyEmitter`.

The big problem you have here is your client has to wait for the response to be 100% prepared before the server can *start* to respond.

Once this period of waiting exceeds the read timeout (usually 30s) you will get timeout errors. Upping the timeout is a very short term solution.

Using the ResponseBodyEmitter allows your server to write the response a line at a time so the initial response is much sooner.

Another avenue to explore would be the Spring Reactive libs. We have apps that return many GB over 10, 20 minutes without issue.

Comment: Can you provide a sample or some resource where I can find how to stream a file and JSON(for another use case) using ```ResponseBodyEmitter```, in case you have used it before.

Comment: A quick Google search shows a couple of examples. Here's one: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/rest/spring-async-controller-responsebodyemitter/

Answer (score 0):

If this API is for end-user as appose to other API, Should consider other communication channel for sending this file like e-mail or create file, upload to some location and return URL instead of file this way user can download it multiple time also.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what the client wants